# Can I say "Intake energy into the grid"?

Tags: word-usage

My UK translator always talk about **sold energy** to the "electric grid" but I need to describe the energy that is put in the grid from a generator (paid or not)

Now I'm also using "**InakenEnergy**" as a variable name inside my programming code. Is it correct?

Comment: I assume you meant to type the variable name *IntakenEnergy*, not ***Inaken...***.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, variable names don't need to be correct English usage in the first place. Good variable naming is about making it obvious to the programmer (and debugger, if they're different people) what the variable is supposed to do.

To that end, IntakenEnergy a fine variable name. (It might disagree with camelCase capitalization conventions, but that's another question.)

From the perspective of English, talking about "the grid" as a container of electrical energy is common usage. The energy that has been put into the grid could correctly be described, from the grid's perspective, as intaken energy.

I might have used a name like *newEnergy*, *inputEnergy*, or *addedEnergy*, but that's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title

> Can I say “Intake energy into the grid”?

no, you can't.  It's comprehensible and just about grammatical but it's not quite natural.  Better would be

> Supply energy to the grid

or

> Input energy into the grid

Personally I don't like this latter form but

> input ... into

has escaped into common usage and it's far beyond my capabilities to eradicate it now.  I prefer

> put ... into

Comment: What about the variable name? May I use "InputtedEnergy"?

Comment: I've nothing to add to what @rsegal has written on the topic of variable names.  You can use whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend InputEnergy.  "Input" is a common term in engineering and programming and those who review or later update your code will instantly recognize the meaning of the variable.  Using "new" or "added" may introduce confusion since those terms could also be associated with time variables or addition operators, respectively.